# Dates showing up instead of passwords in iOS safari

Tags: ios, password

Previously when I tried to log in somewhere safari would show me my 1password login option, I can tap that, it does face ID then fills in the form.

Recently (not exactly sure when, maybe last few weeks) safari has started showing me dates instead. If I click the "key" on the side it shows the 1password login, but usually it's last on the list. If I click the date instead of the correct login, it fills out the form and puts the date in the username.

Is this 1password's bug or some issue with iOS (or safari)? Any idea how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a 1Password issue and unfortunately can't be diagnosed here. In your final screenshot, take note that it says `for store.boingboing.net – 1Password`. This indicates the data was provided by 1Password.

Comment: Thanks I raised a ticket with them. They asked for more info to try to reproduce, unfortunately it's on every form for me. Appreciate your comment.